# Compiling without main function (MacOS)

Tags: c, macos, gcc

So I am trying to compile ,link and run a program without the main function.This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>


int my_main() 
{ 
      printf("Hello world!\n"); 
          return 0; 

} 

void _start() 
{  
      exit(my_main()); 

}
```

Tried to compile with the command : **gcc -nostartfiles nomain.c** . While it does compile and produces the a.out file on a Debian vm, I am unable to compile it in my macOS Catalina v10.15.2. I am using the latest version of gcc. The message I am receiving when trying to compile is :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_main", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So far I have tried to change **_start** to **start** but still getting the same result. As I understand the compilation process is different depending on the OS.

*Note: There is no problem I am trying to solve here , just curiosity.*

Thank you in advance

Comment: Message is clear. OS expected _main, you named it _start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On macOS 10.14.6 with Xcode 11.3, the code in the question compiles and links with the command:

```
clang -Wl,-e, -Wl,__start <Name of Your Source File>
```

The resulting executable appears to work. However, since it bypasses the startup code for the C environment, you should not expect that using routines from the C library or other C features will work properly.

Note that two underscores are needed before `start` in the above command because the source code contains one and another is added by the C compiler. If the code is changed to use `start` instead of `_start`, then the command would use one underscore:

```
clang -Wl,-e, -Wl,_start <Name of Your Source File>
```

The switches `-Wl,-e, -Wl,_start` pass `-e _start` to the linker, which tells it to use `_start` as the address of the initial code to execute. It is not clear to me why this bypasses the default loading of the C-run-time-startup object module, which also defines `_start`. I would have preferred to use a linker switch that tells it not to load that module, but I did not find one in the man page for `ld`. Experimentation suggests that, by default, `ld` loads the default object module, and it refers to `main`, which results in a link error, but, when `-e _start` is used, the linker sets the program’s `_start` symbol as the startup address and does not load the default object module.

Comment: You can just list all of the options and arguments to pass to the linker with a single `-Wl`: `clang -Wl,-e,_start`.

Comment: Great explanation and answer overall , seems that this also works with gcc with -e switch.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can compile any C-source without main().

The problem will be with the linker trying to create an executable, which won't work without main().

Comment: You are right on this one as gcc -c nomain.c does produce an object file, whats weird is that it compiled and linked just fine on Linux...